# How to debug Protocol.dataReceived in Twisted

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I'm new to twisted and I'm having trouble to debug my code within the `dataReceived` method of the `twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol` object.

Given some code like this

```
class Printer(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print data # Works perfectly
        print toto # should trigger some error since "toto" is not defined
...
response.deliverBody(Printer())
```

I couldn't find a way to add an `Errback` on `dataReceived`. Is there a way ? an other way to debug its behavior ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't catch errors from `dataReceived` directly since that function isn't a `deferred` user's generally have control over.  You can only call `addErrback` on `deferred` objects.  Here is an example of how to catch errors:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

class Printer(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        d = Deferred()
        d.addCallback(self.display_data)
        d.addErrback(self.error_func)
        d.callback(data)

    def display_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        print(toto)    # this will raise NameError error

    def error_func(self, error):
        print('[!] Whoops here is the error: {0}'.format(error))
```

A `deferred` is created in the `dataReceived` function which will print `data` and the invalid `toto` variables.  An errorback function (ie. `self.error_func()`) is chained to catch errors that occur in `display_data()`. You should strive very hard to not have errors in the dataReceived function itself. This isn't always possible but one should try.  Hope this helps